# Different return value for multiple calls to function

Tags: python, numpy

I am encountering some strange behavior in my Python (v. 3.8.8) code: Multiple calls of the same function (with exactly the same input) returns different values. The code below reproduces the issue.

**Expected behavior**: Each call of the function with exactly the same input parameters should return the same output. In other words, the value of `zmin` should be constant for all iterations.

**Observed behavior**: Each call to the function gives a (slightly) different output, even though the input parameters are the same: `zmin` in the example is not constant. The difference is quite large, for instance the code below gives: zmin = array([1.94777151, 1.95983567, 1.97510284, 1.99350764, 2.01497125, 2.03940178, 2.0666946 , 2.09673286, 2.12938792, 2.16451995]).

Why does this happen?

The issue persists regardless of whether the helper function `quarternion_mul` is vectorized using `@guvectorize`.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import guvectorize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Update MC cycle parameters
def change_to(state,position=None,rotation=None):
    """Update the current state to the state described by the center of mass
    position and the applied rotation.
    """
    # If provided, apply rotation to all points:
    point = np.zeros(4,dtype=float)
    if rotation is not None:
        rotation_inverse = np.array([rotation[0], -rotation[1],
                                      -rotation[2], -rotation[3]])
        for i in range(1,state.shape[0]):
            # Translate center of mass to origin
            coords = state[i,:3] - state[0,:3]
            point[0] = 0.0
            point[1:] = coords
            # Apply rotation
            rp = quaternion_mul(rotation,point)
            rpr_inv = quaternion_mul(rp,rotation_inverse)
            state[i,:3] = rpr_inv[1:] + state[0,:3]
      
    # Move points to target location
    delta = np.zeros(len(state[0,:]),dtype=float)
    delta[:3] = position - state[0,:3]
    return state + delta

# Function to calculate Hamilton product
@guvectorize(['(float64[:], float64[:], float64[:])'], '(n),(n)->(n)', nopython=True, target="parallel")
def quaternion_mul(a,b,c):
    # Hamilton quaternion product
    c[0] = a[0]*b[0] - a[1]*b[1] - a[2]*b[2] - a[3]*b[3]
    c[1] = a[0]*b[1] + a[1]*b[0] + a[2]*b[3] - a[3]*b[2]
    c[2] = a[0]*b[2] - a[1]*b[3] + a[2]*b[0] + a[3]*b[1]
    c[3] = a[0]*b[3] + a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1] + a[3]*b[0]

# def quaternion_mul(a,b):
#     # Hamilton quaternion product
#     c = np.zeros(4)
#     c[0] = a[0]*b[0] - a[1]*b[1] - a[2]*b[2] - a[3]*b[3]
#     c[1] = a[0]*b[1] + a[1]*b[0] + a[2]*b[3] - a[3]*b[2]
#     c[2] = a[0]*b[2] - a[1]*b[3] + a[2]*b[0] + a[3]*b[1]
#     c[3] = a[0]*b[3] + a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1] + a[3]*b[0]
#     return c


start_state = np.array([[-0.053442, 2.05268,    1.92046,    0,  0,  0,  0],
[1.02709,   1.6784, 1.03511,    0.6365, 11310,  10156,  1],
[0.956003,  2.04269,    0.949338,   0.5853, 8225,   11248,  0],
[0.615004,  2.05092,    0.784356,   0.6365, 12229,  14318,  0],
[0.488786,  2.28627,    0.520153,   0.4509, 8414,   9459,   0],
[0.174876,  2.47819,    0.607007,   0.6563, 13127,  11105,  1],
[-0.0532915,    2.29712,    0.359422,   0.5477, 9610,   7634,   0],
[0.107118,  1.95669,    0.407201,   0.5927, 10666,  8236,   -1],
[0.0313548, 1.98191,    0.781065,   0.6187, 7632,   7583,   0]],dtype=float)

position = np.array([0,0,3.5])
rotation = np.array([0.9994646047913096,    0.0146483594354613, 
                     -0.0194742908484703,   0.0218330330268212])

iters = 10
zmin = np.zeros(iters)
for i in range(iters):
    end = change_to(start_state,
                    position=position,
                    rotation=rotation)
    zmin[i] = np.min(end[1:,2])
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just floating point imprecision? You can use np.isclose to check if the value between the different runs are close to each other (i.e. supposed to be the same, but different due to floating point error)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. The error is much larger than a floating point error. The code above gives for ```zmin``` = array([1.94777151, 1.95983567, 1.97510284, 1.99350764, 2.01497125,
       2.03940178, 2.0666946 , 2.09673286, 2.12938792, 2.16451995]). A floating point error would not be such an issue, but differences of several percent are quite significant. I have updated my question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying `start_state`.

Comment: You beat me to it! Indeed, the line `state[i,:3] = rpr_inv[1:] + state[0,:3]` modifies `start_state`, so that it's not the same input each time.

Comment: And, before the OP asks, isn't `state` a local variable in the function? Yes, it is, but you are not assigning to the variable, you are assigning to a slice of an array, and that means modifying the existing array object.

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to fix the issue by making a deep copy of the input (```state```) using ```copy.deepcopy(state)``` and modifying the new variable. This feels a little bit like a botched solution; is this the way to go or would there be a better (simple) solution?

Comment: I'll leave that to someone else to answer. :) I suppose it would be nice if the new state could somehow be built directly rather than assembling it piecewise from the old state, but I haven't studied the code enough to know whether that is possible. When dealing with numpy, looping over axis dimensions and lots of indexing exercise is often (but not always) an indication that there's a neater (and faster!) way of doing it but, again, I haven't checked.